# Compute the variance of the random variable X measuring the distance between P1 and P2

Tags: probability, variance, geometric-probability

Can anyone help me with this?

Consider the circle $C = \{f(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}$ and a point P2\in\mathbb{C}. A point P2\in\mathbb{C} is
randomly chosen.

Compute the variance of the random variable X measuring the distance between P1 and P2.

The average between two points is 2rsin(θ/2) where θ is in [0,π].
But how can a find the pdf?

Comment: The circle is not $C = \{f(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: x^2 + y^2 = r^2\};$ rather it is $C = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}. \qquad$

Comment: And what you call the "average" is the distance. The average wouldn't contain $\theta$ as a free variable.

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags. (Tags matter; I could have directly closed this as a duplicate if you'd correctly tagged it with [tag:probability]; now it will need to accumulate $5$ votes.)

Comment: @joriki five votes or one more from someone with the gold probability badge  :D